# How to get notification if a CRM Workflow is not succeeded

Tags: view, dynamics-crm, workflow, crm

I have a background workflow in Dynamic CRM 2015. I want to send a notification to the user or create a monitor view in dashboard to show any workflow process's status is not succeeded, ex. failed, waiting and canceled. Is there any solutions to reach this goal?

Answer (score 1):

This already exists, its the system jobs view, there is an area for this in the settings, you may also be able to add the systems job view to a dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Very late in the conversation. Just sharing my thoughts.
Dynamics 
One way would be to create a custom entity to keep a record of error logs(*new_log*). Now, create a workflow to send email when a record is created in *new_log* entity.

Now we face a problem how to create record in *new_log* entity because as far as I know CRM does not allow us to trigger plugin/workflow on *systemjob(asyncoperation)*.
So, to create a record in *new_log* entity you would have to write code inside the workflow.
Hope it helps.